# Disk storage space indicator in ubuntu

Tags: gui, filemanager

Is their any application or gui or file manager in ubuntu that shows disk space used/free like windows graphically in file explorer

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J21It.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of gui apps for disk analysis as illustrated by this link [here](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-disk-analyzer-tools-for-linux-system/) Many are available in the Ubuntu software centre.

These may be more complicated than you want. However you will get exactly the information you are looking for with the `df -h` terminal command.

Comment: Thank you fot the replay but I am in search of a simple tool that shows only how much Disk capacity is used&free like windows explorer file manger and not intrested in space occupied by directories and files inside disk and also right clicking on individual disk properties in file manager does the job but looking for tool which shows size of every disk mounted in system

Comment: Depending on which desktop you are using there may be a widget that will show this information. You could also try conky